# Is code completion available in QGIS Python Console?

Tags: python, qgis

I wanted to know if the autofill functionality is available in the python console for QGIS as the one available in ArcGIS Desktop's Python Console or am I supposed to hardcode it.

Comment: Do you mean code completion?

Comment: Yes, the code completion

Answer (score 3):

The QGIS Python console has now been [upgraded](http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/five-new-awesomely-awesome-qgis-features-round-2/) in the latest dev version to include code completion, among a lot of other tweaks and features.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no code completion in QGIS python console as far as I know. But I'm sure it can be added if a sponsor can be found.

Until then, the API docs are the reference: http://qgis.org/api/

Comment: QGIS' Python window needs a _lot_ of love to compare to other interactive Python consoles.