# Can I make QGIS Python console autocompletion work for imported libs?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

In the QGIS Python console there is code completion available since a while (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20469/is-code-completion-available-in-qgis-python-console)). However it seems to be quite limited as to its range, according to the doc the following libs are supported:

```
Code completion, highlighting syntax and calltips for the following APIs: 
- Python
- PyQGIS
- PyQt5
- QScintilla2
- osgeo-gdal-ogr
```

Obviously this makes coding directly within QGIS cumbersome, especially if one is used to the comfort-level of modern IDEs. I configured pyCharm to reflect the QGIS environment, so that it knows how to autocomplete on qgis.core and so on, but copying and pasting code from a secondary IDE is circumstancial.

**Is there a way to have auto-completion on imported libs (e.g. `os` or `math`) directly within the QGIS console/editor?**

---

I can confirm that I get auto-completion suggestions only for basic python and the abovementioned libs.

[image: here code completion suggests some tings (for auto)]

For (even very basic) imported libs (e.g. `math` or `os`) this doesn't work:

[image: but e.g. for the imported math lib I have no code completion]

Comment: Are you aware that you can connect the Python console to an external editor? Click the `Show Editor` button at the top of the Python console and then click the `Open In External Editor` button at the top of the script editor pane. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381719/configuring-qgis-for-external-editor).

Comment: I am aware, yes. However as far as I see that just is another way of copying and pasting, as I'm still switching between windows to debug (instead of just pressing Ctrl+E in the QGIS Script Editor or simply coding in the console directly, I would code in pyCharm, save, then execute from QGIS Script Editor or copy and paste to console). I know, first world problems - I'm looking for a convenient PyQGIS dev workflow while maintaining the WYSIWYG-aspect of working directly in QGIS. Improving on the IDE capacities of QGIS would be the easiest.